# agregar dos valores de Vuejs a href

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

Como haria para arrastrar los dos valores a la url ya que me esta arrojando un cero ejemplo: url: google/0 lo cual no deberia pasar, cuando quito uno de las dos ( '+proyecto.id_proyecto&+idUsuario ) y arreglo lo demas para que trabaje con una si funciona. Como haria para que funcione con dos valores (son numeros las dos)

```
<td v-if="permisoCrear">
  <a v-bind:href="'/formCargarHoras/'+proyecto.id_proyecto/+idUsuario" target="_self">
    <i class="fas fa-user-edit" v-if="proyecto.permisoCrear"></i>
</td>
```

Esta vendría siendo la direccion del router para capturar los dos valores y usarlos luego llevarlas al controller para abrir la nueva ventana

```
Route::get('/formCargarHoras/{idProyecto}/{idUsuario}', 'ProyectoController@formCargarHoras')->where('idProyecto', '[0-9]+');//Validamos que solo pase números*/
```

Y aqui agregaria los dos valores con un put a la nueva ventana

```
function formCargarHoras($idProyecto, $idUsuario, Request $request) {
  $request->session()->put('idProyecto',$idProyecto,'idUsuario', $idUsuario);
  return view('horasCargables/CargarHoras');
}
```

Comment: Antes de concatenar el string con js... Funciona esa ruta en Laravel? Es medio raro ese signo `&` en esa parte de la url

Comment: disculpa un error mio lo puse para ver si agarraba, tengo es / en esa parte ya lo acomode

Comment: Prueba poniendo esa barra inclinada entre comillas como hiciste con la otra parte `"'/formCargarHoras/'+proyecto.id_proyecto+'/'+idUsuario"`

Comment: funciono gracias